# Scala, Either[_, Seq[Either[_, T]] to Either[_, Seq[T]]

Tags: scala, monads, either

Here's the scaste for the code below: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bQMGrAKgRoOFaK1lwCy04g

I've a two JSON API endpoints. First, `items.cgi`, returns list of item objects in the following format

```
$ curl http://example.com/items.cgi
[
    ...
    { sn: "KXB1333", ownerId: 3, borrowerId: 0 },
    { sn: "KCB1200", ownerId: 1, borrowerId: 2 },
    ...
]
```

`borrowerId == 0` means item has no borrower.

Second, `users.cgi`, returns user specified by `id` query parameter

```
$ curl http://example.com/user.cgi?id=1
{ id: 1, name: "frank" }
```

The API may be bad but I have to deal with it. Now in Scala I'd like to work with this nice data model

```
case class User(id: Int, name: String)
case class Item(sn: String, owner: User, borrower: Option[User])
```

I also have the following for doing HTTP requests

```
case class ApiFail(reason: String)
def get[T](url: String): Either[ApiFail, T] = ??? /* omitted for brevity */
```

The `get()` function uses some magic to fetch a JSON from an URL and construct a `T` out of it (it uses some libraries). On IO failure or bad HTTP status it returns `Left`.

I'd like to write the following function

```
def getItems: Either[ApiFail, Seq[Item]]
```

It should fetch the list of items, for each item fetch the linked users and return a new list of `Item`s or fail on **any** HTTP request failure. (There may be redundant requests for users with a same ID but I don't care about *memoization*/*caching* yet.)

So far I only managed to write this function

```
def getItems: Either[ApiFail, Seq[Either[ApiFail, Item]]]
```

where a failure to retrieve some user is fatal only for the corresponding item and not the whole result. Here's the implementation

```
def getItems: Either[ApiFail, Seq[Either[ApiFail, Item]]] = {
    case class ItemRaw(sn: String, ownerId: Int, borrowerId: Int)

    get[List[ItemRaw]]("items.cgi").flatMap(itemRawList => Right(
        itemRawList.map(itemRaw => {
            for {
                owner <- get[User](s"users.cgi?id=${itemRaw.ownerId}")
                borrower <-
                    if (itemRaw.borrowerId > 0)
                        get[User](s"users.cgi?id=${itemRaw.borrowerId}").map(Some(_))
                    else
                        Right(None)
            } yield
                Item(itemRaw.sn, owner, borrower)
        })
    ))
}
```

This seems like a request for a homework but it occurs to me frequently that I want to switch from one *wrapper thing* (m-monad?) to another and I'm a bit puzzled as to how to do it with *wrapper functions* (c-combinators?) only. I could of course switch to an imperative implementation. I'm just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a word for doing exactly this in the FP world - "Traverse" ([link to cats implementation](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/Traverse.scala)). It's used when you have an `F[A]` and a function `A => G[B]` and you want a `G[F[B]]`. Here, `F` is `List`, `A` is `ItemRaw`, `G` is `Either[ApiFail, _]`, and `B` is `Item`. Of course there are some constraints on what `F` and `G` can be.

Using cats, you can change your method very slightly:

```
import cats._, cats.implicits._

def getItems: Either[ApiFail, Seq[Item]] = {
  case class ItemRaw(sn: String, ownerId: Int, borrowerId: Int)

  get[List[ItemRaw]]("items.cgi").flatMap(itemRawList =>
    itemRawList.traverse[({type T[A]=Either[ApiFail, A]})#T, Item](itemRaw => {
      for {
        owner <- get[User](s"users.cgi?id=${itemRaw.ownerId}")
        borrower <-
          if (itemRaw.borrowerId > 0)
            get[User](s"users.cgi?id=${itemRaw.borrowerId}").map(Some(_))
          else
            Right(None)
      } yield
        Item(itemRaw.sn, owner, borrower)
    })
  )
}
```

With that said, I can certainly understand being hesitant to go fully down that route. cats (and scalaz) are a lot to take in - though I recommend you do at some point!

Without them, you can always write your own utility methods for manipulating your commonly-used containers:

```
def seqEither2EitherSeq[A, B](s: Seq[Either[A, B]]): Either[A, Seq[B]] = {
  val xs: Seq[Either[A, Seq[B]]] = s.map(_.map(b => Seq(b)))
  xs.reduce{ (e1, e2) => for (x1 <- e1; x2 <- e2) yield x1 ++ x2 }
}

def flattenEither[A, B](e: Either[A, Either[A, B]]): Either[A, B] = e.flatMap(identity)
```

Then the result you want would be:

```
val result: Either[ApiFail, Seq[Item]] = flattenEither(getItems.map(seqEither2EitherSeq))
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. There's a lot to learn. The type parameters for `traverse` are somewhat puzzling. I've seen in the sources that it takes 3, but you only specify two. It works without type parameters with `-Ypartial-unification` scalac flag. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/8c1pdg7eTeqzQGRUDLPQOw

Comment: cats uses simulacrum (https://github.com/mpilquist/simulacrum) to provide some additional syntax for typeclasses. So the traverse method I'm calling is actually in some generated `Traverse.Ops` class or similar, with an implicit conversion from `List`. The `F` and `A` type parameters are obtained from the object I'm calling it on (`itemRawList`) so only the `G` and `B` type parameters are needed.